# How do you use a switch statement to check an int type as blank in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a temporary local variable to check against a value pulled in from a SP using a switch statement. I've declared these members as int types and the value of the value of the SP will either be 0, 1, or blank. It is treating the statement that compares against blank as a string when it is an int. How can I fix this?

```
private int checkInventoryValue(int returnedval)
{
   int testedValue = (int)returnedval;
   switch (testedValue)
   { 
       case 1:
           testedValue = 0;
           break;
       case 2:
           testedValue = 1;
           break;
       default:
           testedValue = ""; // error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' 
           break;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ints can't be blank (unless you make them nullable which is a totally different thing).

Comment: You might want to look at what a blank value becomes when you convert it into a int.  You could add an explicit case for that.  It's good to avoid using NULLs in general in programming.

Answer (score 3):

```
private int? checkInventoryValue(int returnedval)
{
    int? testedValue = (int?)returnedval;
    switch (returnedval)
    { 
        case 1:
            testedValue = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            testedValue = 1;
            break;
        default:
            testedValue = null; 
            break;
    }
    return testedValue;
}
```

Later(up the chain) you can convert that to a empty string if you really want to

Comment: You dont need to cast in the first line; `returnedvalue` is already an int, and you never return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Integers can not be blank, however, you can use a nullable integer:

```
int? testedValue = (int?)returnedval;
switch (testedValue.Value)
{ 
    case 1:
        testedValue = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        testedValue = 1;
        break;
    default:
        testedValue = null; // error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' 
        break;
}
```